# How to filter lists in a list?

Tags: python, list, filter

I have, e.g., listy = [[1,-1,2], [3,-2,-4]]

I want to filter such that I get just the positive elements [[1,2], [3]]

This is easy to do with a loop and filter(lambda x: x > 0, listy), but I'd like to avoid a loop.

Comment: I don't believe that there is anyway to go about this without some sort of loop. Plus 1 if anyone knows different ^^

Comment: @T.Woody: Depends on what you count as a loop. Is recursion a loop? Is a loop unrolled into a bunch of repetitive code a loop? I think the answer is "As far as anything that matters is concerned, yet", but others may disagree; see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions can be nested:

```
In [2]: [ [i for i in x if i>0] for x in listy ]
Out[2]: [[1, 2], [3]]
```

Regarding the choice between `filter` and list comprehension, [Guido van Rossum, the BDFL, wrote](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) that list comprehension is both clearer and faster;

> filter(P, S) is almost always written clearer as [x for x in S if
>   P(x)], and this has the huge advantage that the most common usages
>   involve predicates that are comparisons, e.g. x==42, and defining a
>   lambda for that just requires much more effort for the reader (plus
>   the lambda is slower than the list comprehension).

#### Advanced Topic: Handling large datasets

If `listy` is large and your application permits, you may want to use generators in place of lists:

```
g = ( (i for i in x if i>0) for x in listy )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem pretty much inherently requires a loop. You want to do something for each member of `listy`, the `for` is there even in English.

However, you *can* wrap the loop up inside a comprehension, or a call to `map`, etc. For example:

```
listy = map(lambda sublist: filter(lambda x: x>0, sublist), listy)
listy = [[x for x in sublist if x>0] for sublist in listy]
```

(Or, of course, the other two combinations of the above, a comprehension over `filter`, or a `map` over a comprehension.)

You can also do the looping lazily, so instead of wasting time up front creating the filtered lists, you just create iterators that will generate the positive values on demand:

```
itery = itertools.imap(lambda sublist: itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x>0, sublist), listy)
itery = ((x for x in sublist if x>0) for sublist in listy)
```

But that just means the looping happens later, when you iterate over each element of `itery`, rather than right away.

(And again, you can combine the above two ideas, e.g., a list of iterators or an iterator of lists, instead of an iterator of iterators or a list of lists.)

You can even hide the loop inside a NumPy element-wise operation by creating a 1D array of Python lists and calling `vectorize(lambda lst: filter(lambda x: x>0, sublist))` on it. But the loop's still going to be there.

---

Of course you could also get around the loop by looping *indirectly*. For example, with recursion:

```
def filter_nonpositives(x):
    return x[:x[0]>0] + filter_nonpositives(x[1:])
```

Or even by unrolling the loop up to some maximum size:

```
def filter_nonpositives(x):
    result = []
    if len(x) == 0:
        return result
    if x[0] > 0:
        result.append(x[0])
    if len(x) == 1:
        return result
    if x[1] > 0:
        result.append(x[1])
    if len(x) == 2:
        return result
    if x[2] > 0:
        result.append(x[2])
    # ... repeat as far as you want
    return result
```

But either way, you're still effectively looping—and you'd be hard-pressed to find anyone who thinks either one is more Pythonic, or better.