# Python list of lists comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of lists V which, if converted in a numpy array, has a shape (9945,1024). Each list inside contain some value, and I want to create a list of lists which contains lists with values under a certain treshold. For instance, if I have:

```
a = [[1,3,4],[1,0,1],[0,5,1]]
```

and I want only values less than 2, I should have:

```
a = [[1],[1,0,1],[0,5,1]]
```

How can I get this?
I tried first with a boolean:

```
boolean_V = ([V[i] >= V_max for i in range (0,len(V))])
```

And then I did:

```
V_new = V[boolean_V]
```

But I find (once converted) a numpy array of shape (3090669). What can I do?

Comment: it may not be recommended practice to make ragged arrays as that ruins performance with numpy, maybe you want to replace them with 0 instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter lists in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068859/how-to-filter-lists-in-a-list)

Comment: I'm sorry, what does this have to do with numpy?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is we have an AxB sized array. Given we are using a numpy array, after we filter, we still need to have an AxB array. However, if we turn this into a list, we can have different sized rows. This can be achieved with something like this:

```
filter_list = [[val for val in row if val < 2] for row in a]
```

If you do still need it to be a numpy array, you can convert this list to a numpy array, and specify `dtype=object` for varied row sizes.

```
filter_array = np.array(filter_list, dtype=object)
```

You could also make a mask with something like this to indicate what positions meet the condition

```
mask = np.abs(test) < 2

print(mask)

array([[ True, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [ True, False,  True]])
```

Which will given back a similar dimensioned array telling if that val at each index met the condition

Comment: Hi maybe a mask would be better because then I have to select the times (from another array) for which we have V <= V_max, what can I do?

Comment: Anyway, still get an array with shape 9945, while I get a list of correct dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
threshold = 2
b = [[j for j in i if j <= threshold] for i in a]
```

Comment: Anyway, still get an array with shape 9945, while I get a list of correct dimensions

Answer (score 0):

If you want the final result to be a list of not necessarily equal lengths you can do something like this:

```
for row in range(V):
   V[row] = list(filter(lambda x : x <= V_max, V[row]))
```

This would iterate through each list inside the big list and keep only the values below the set threshold.

Comment: Anyway, still get an array with shape 9945, while I get a list of correct dimensions